# ASP.NET MVC 5 - JSON - (Dynamic?) Model Binding - REST services - Webhooks - Chargebee

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, webhooks

This should be easy but I'm stuck. I've set up a webhook with a service (ChargeBee) that is successfully posting my site JSON. Here is the model I'm trying to bind:

```
public class ChargeBeeWebhookModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string occurred_at { get; set; }

    public string source { get; set; }

    public string @object { get; set; }        

    public string content { get; set; }

    public string event_type { get; set; }

    public string webhook_status { get; set; }
}
```

Everything is binding except "content", which is null. The problem is that "content" will change depending on what type of event is triggered. It could be something like this for example, for the "customer created" event:

```
 "customer": {
        "id": "8avVGOkx8U1MX",
        "first_name": "Benjamin",
        "last_name": "Ross",
        "email": "Benjamin@test.com",
        "auto_collection": "on",
        "created_at": 1317407411,
        "object": "customer",
        "card_status": "valid",
        "payment_method": {
            "object": "payment_method",
            "type": "card",
            "gateway": "chargebee",
            "reference_id": "tok_KyVr8xPHl5BSx1",
            "status": "valid"
        },
        "account_credits": 0
    },
    "card": {
        "customer_id": "8avVGOkx8U1MX",
        "status": "valid",
        "gateway": "chargebee",
        "iin": "411111",
        "last4": "1111",
        "card_type": "visa",
        "expiry_month": 1,
        "expiry_year": 2016,
        "object": "card",
        "masked_number": "************1111"
    }
```

I just need to bind these complex objects to some type. String isn't working. Once it's bound, I can easily check if it's an event I want to handle using the event_type property and deserialize it into the appropriate custom type.

How do I do this? I feel like I'm missing something really simple. Chargebee won't let me have a different URL for each type of event as far as I know, which is what I thought would make the most sense. It's one URL and I have to bind many possible responses.

Do I need a custom model binder or something? Is there an easier way?

Also maybe someone could make a ChargeBee tag?

Thanks everyone.

---

EDIT:

---

As requested, this is what the sample request looks like:

```
Headers
POST HTTP/1.1
Host:********.ngrok.io //(obviously I commented this out)
Authorization: Basic cGF0cmlvdGN5YmVybmV0aWNzZHJvbmVtYXN0ZXI6c3VuZGV2aWxjb2NvYXJhZ2luZ2J1bGw=
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: ChargeBee

Body
{
    "id": "ev_3Nl8ERLPElBCRU6",
    "occurred_at": 1341167306,
    "source": "admin_console",
    "object": "event",
    "content": {
        "subscription": {
            "id": "3Nl8ERLPElBCGl1",
            "plan_id": "basic",
            "plan_quantity": 1,
            "status": "future",
            "start_date": 1341772105,
            "trial_start": 1341772105,
            "trial_end": 1344450505,
            "created_at": 1341167305,
            "has_scheduled_changes": false,
            "object": "subscription",
            "addons": [{
                "id": "data_usage",
                "quantity": 1,
                "object": "addon"
            }],
            "due_invoices_count": 0
        },
        "customer": {
            "id": "3Nl8ERLPElBCGl1",
            "first_name": "Benjamin",
            "last_name": "Ross",
            "email": "Benjamin@test.com",
            "auto_collection": "on",
            "created_at": 1341167305,
            "object": "customer",
            "card_status": "valid",
            "payment_method": {
                "object": "payment_method",
                "type": "card",
                "reference_id": "3Nl8ERLPElBCGl1",
                "status": "valid"
            }
        }
    },
    "event_type": "subscription_created",
    "webhook_status": "not_configured"
}
```

Unless I'm mistaken, I just don't think the model binder can handle this situation. It needs pre-defined types and can't handle variability or dynamic stuff as far as I can tell. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Anyway, I'll answer this question with a full code sample later but for now I've ditched a pure model-binding approach and am reading the Request.InputStream to get the JSON data I need. Then, depending on event_type, which the model binder had no problems with, I'm deserializing into my predefined types. It's just that I've never actually had to manually pick something out of a request before; I've always used the model binder.

Comment: Why isn't string working? You could store the json representation of content as a string and then check the event_type and invoke the appropriate content serializer then.

Comment: I don't know. That's what I expected to happen. That's why I wrote this question.

Comment: Can you share an example of a request you make to the controller? More specifically I want to see how you specify parameters in your request body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I was trying to achieve. Request.InputStream is the way to go; I started trying to do this manually but luckily ChargeBee has an official .NET library (unlike Mandrill) to do it all for me:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [BasicAuthentication(username: "x", password: "y", BasicRealm = "z")]
    public HttpStatusCodeResult ChargeBeeWebhook()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {          
            Event chargeBeeEvent = new Event(Request.InputStream);

            EventTypeEnum? eventType = chargeBeeEvent.EventType;

            Event.EventContent eventContent = chargeBeeEvent.Content;

            if (eventType == EventTypeEnum.SubscriptionCreated)
            {
                Subscription subscription = eventContent.Subscription;

                Customer customer = eventContent.Customer;

                // more stuff
            }          

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400); // bad request
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay the following should work. Instead of passing a Javascript object for content, use JSON.stringify on your object and set the result of it to content. This way in your Controller the value of content will be a string.

Comment: That would be fine if I were sending the request. But I'm not. ChargeBee is. This is a webhook situation. They post my system data whenever something happens in their system that affects my system. But thanks man the JSON.stringify() thing is something I'll remember.

Comment: Oh okay my bad. I have another idea but you may not like it. Remove content from your model so that when model binding is happening, content will be ignored. Then in your Action, look at your Request body and find the Content argument. Will update this answer with a sample in a short while.